# Setting default on Mongoose subschema automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am looking for a way to have Mongoose automatically fill in a field with a generated value. I thought the following would work but it's a no go. Is it possible to autofill a sub schema field on save? (not looking for middleware code - just automatic)

```
// A function to gen an integer
function randomValue () {
   var s = parseInt(crypto.randomBytes(4).toString('hex'), 16);
   return s;
}

// Subschema 
var Variation = new Schema({
  // Set default to gen integer
  code: {
    type: Number,
    default: randomValue
  } 
},{ _id : false });

// Main schema
var Product = new Schema({     
  variations: {
    type: [Variation]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to invoke randomValue in order to return the value of s

Comment: huh?  No you don't - that will just set it once on Schema launch and never give you a random value -  it works fine on main schema just not sub